# using <li> on each newline

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have following pattern in every single cell in the coloumn in Libre Calc -

```
Spec One: This is one
Spec Two: This is spec two
Spec Three: This is spec three
```

Is there any way to convert this to -

```
<li>Spec One: This is one</li>
<li>Spec Two: This is spec two</li>
<li>Spec Three: This is spec three</li>
```

The entry was done using 'Ctrl+Enter' after every spec. TIA.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ - it's probably a line feed, new line or carriage return. Find & replace

Comment: I did. But am not able to get starting and end of a line via regular expression. I got the newline using `\n` delimiter. Now, all I need is to wrap the whole string in one starting `<li>` and one ending `</li>`. Like `<li>THE STRING</li>`

Comment: I got the END OF STRING by using `$` and replaced it with `</li>`. It's 2000 rows, hence manual entry of `<li>` i START OF STRING is tedious.

Comment: Sorted. Thanks for all the help @Raystafarian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by the following method:

First I searched for `\n` and replaced it with `<li></li>`. This gave me starting and ending `li` on every new line in a single string output.

Then I searched for `$` and replaced it with `</li>`. This gave me ending `li` at the end of the string that was outputted from above method.

Then I used the following formula to insert `<li>` in starting of the string. Used this formula in adjacent blank cell and dragged it till the end for getting all cells output.

`=CONCATENATE("<li>";A1;)`

Comment: For the last step, a regex search for `^(.*)` and replace with `<li>$1` should have done the trick, too.